# Basic equation of trigonomenty, existence of an angle.

Tags: complex-numbers

I have a question, which was surely asked a lot of times, but I can't find it.
If $x^2 + y^2 = 1$, is it true that always exists $z$ such that $sinz=x$ and $cosz=y$?
It seems so, but I came across an equation in which from this assumption a contradiction could be derived, and I can't see what else could be wrong. So, is it?

Comment: Wish I could know the  equation

Comment: Yes, it is true, since $\;|x|,|y|\le 1\;$ and both sine and cosine are surjective functions on $\;[-1,1]\;$

Comment: @DonAntonio, but the tag is complex number, so can't we take $z$ to be complex?

Comment: I missed the tag (I almost always do), but the answer still is "it's true". Passing to the exponential form can be easier, though.

Comment: Pleaaaase, post the equation !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every pair of real numbers $(x,y)$ such that $x^2+y^2=1$ there exists a real number $z $ such that $\sin z = x$ and $\cos z=x$. One way to see this is to find $z\in [-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ such that $\sin z =x$ (using the intermediate value theorem) and then observe that $\cos z \in \{ \pm y\}$. Hence, either $z$ or $\pi-z$    works.

Every real number is a complex number, which makes the answer to "can we take $z$ to be complex?" trivially yes. If you meant to ask for $z$ with nonzero imaginary part, then the answer is no in general: for example, $\sin z=0$ only when $z \in 2\pi \mathbb Z$.

If $x$ and $y$ are allowed to be complex, still subject to $x^2+y^2=1$, you can still find such $z\in\mathbb C$. Indeed, the sine function $z\mapsto \sin z$ is a surjection of complex plane onto itself (every odd entire function is onto $\mathbb C$, which follows easily from Picard's theorem). Thus, we can find $z$ such that $\sin z=x$. Then again $\cos z \in\{\pm y\}$, which implies that either $z$ or $\pi-z$  works.